# "Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1[System.String]' in c#

Tags: c#, .net

I'm getting the following error

```
"Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1[System.String]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[BookingApp.CustomerRoles]'."}
```

Below is my code where I'm trying to return List of CustomerRoles

```
public virtual List<CustomerRoles> roleByname(string name)
    {
        var mapping = repo.GetAll<BookingMapping>(x => x.Customer.name == name).Include(x => x.Customer).Include(x => x.CustomerRole);
        //var roles = mapping.Select(v => v.CustomerRole.RoleName).ToList();
        List<CustomerRoles> userRoles = (List<CustomerRoles>)mapping.Select(v => v.CustomerRole.RoleName);
        return userRoles;
    }
```

customerRoles class

```
public enum CustomerRoles{
    EndUser,
    ShopAdmin,
    ShopSupervisor
}
```

I have added all the code details also I tried using ToList(), but it throw an error.
I should return a list of CustomerRoles

could someone help me with this?

Comment: What is `repo` ?

Comment: Remove `.RoleName` from the select `Select(v => v.CustomerRole.RoleName)` --> `Select(v => v.CustomerRole);` unless you're after a list of role names in which case the return type should be `IEnumerable<string>`

Comment: @itsme please provide the code for BookingMapping and Customer

Comment: From your code, I guess you are trying to convert `List<string>` to `List<CustomerRoles>` which is enum? And do also show us what is the sample value for `v.CustomerRole.RoleName`.

Comment: @AbdelkrimBournane Added the code for BookingMapping and Customer

Comment: @YongShun added the mapping code

Comment: You do understand that `.Select(v => v.CustomerRole.RoleName)` leaves you with an `IEnumerable<string>` that (when iterated) provides you with the role names, right? How could you possible assign that to a list of `CustomerRole`?

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama it leaves me with List<string>

Comment: You literally select all the `RoleName` property values. In your own model, they are strings. (you haven't provided that, but it's clear they are). You therefore get an `IEnumerable<string>`, and if you call `.ToList()` on it, you get a `List<string>`. You need to assign them to a `List<string>` not a `List<CustomerRole>`.

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama  ok got it. how can i convert List<string> to  List<CustomerRole>

Comment: Isn't `v.CustomerRole` _already_ a `CustomerRole`? If you want that, why don't you just select that instead?

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama v.CustomerRole has other parameters but I need only CustomerRole

Comment: Well, map it from one type to the other by using `.Select` and constructing the `CustomerRole` class.

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama I tried but was not able to get it.could you please help me on this

Comment: @itsme I don't see RoleName in the CustomerRole class...

Comment: @AbdelkrimBournane see updated .it was typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have a string that is a string representing a RoleName, you have to parse from that to the desired enum.

You can do that using the `Parse()` Method, and you have to call ToList() if you want to convert it to a list:

`List<CustomerRoles> userRoles = (List<CustomerRoles>)mapping.Select(v => Enum.Parse<CustomerRoles>(v.CustomerRole.RoleName)).ToList();`

Comment: already tried this and get following error : cannot convert an expression of type System.Collections.Generic.List<string> to type List<CustomerRoles>

Comment: Ok @itsme then please provide the code for BookingMapping and Customer.